# Is encoding a custom object using nscoder and saving to nsuserdefaults encrypted?

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I know saving directly to nsuserdefaults is not encrypted from other answered questions. However, I wasn't sure if using nscoder and decoder made it encrypted. In my case, I have custom class object which I encode and then save using NSuserdefaults.

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/a/45252

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not encrypted. The keychain is encrypted, but NSCoder does not do any encryption, nor is NSUserDefaults encrypted.

You could apply encryption to the `Data` that comes out of `NSCoder` before writing it to `UserDefaults`, and then decrypt it after reading.

Note that you're not supposed to save large blocks of data to `UserDefaults`. It's supposed to be used for simple user settings.